# Is there a ILMerge equivalent tool for Mono?

Tags: c#, mono, assemblies, ilmerge

I'm looking for a open source tool to merge multiple .NET assemblies into a single assembly.

Answer (score 20):

Check [ILRepack](https://github.com/gluck/il-repack), which allows merge of symbol files, xml documentation, App.config and more.
It's open-source and based on [Cecil](https://github.com/jbevain/cecil/wiki). There is also NAnt and MSBuild integration for it in a project called [ILRepack-BuildTasks](https://github.com/zippy1981/ILRepack-BuildTasks)
.

Answer (score 2):

mkbundle and monolinker:
http://www.mono-project.com/Linker

You can also make your own linker tool using Cecil:
https://github.com/jbevain/cecil/wiki

Answer (score 1):

Mono.Merge

http://evain.net/blog/articles/2006/11/06/an-introduction-to-mono-merge

Comment: Unforunately, that project was never completed and is no longer active.