# Generate single exe file in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: .net, exe

I'm trying to develop a very simple application to launch a PDF from a CD (the app will autorun from the same CD).

I just downloaded VS2012 and so far I only manage to build and generate an installer for my app, but I don't know how to generate a single exe file which doesn't need to be installed.

Thank you

Comment: Sorry, I see I can find it under debug directory when compiling, so I guess just compiling without building or publishing is right

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use something like [ILMerge](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/ilmerge.aspx).

This tool from Microsoft enables you to "link" all DLLs and your executable together into one executable file.

There are also [alternatives to ILMerge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655838/is-there-a-ilmerge-equivalent-tool-for-mono) that work similar to ILMerge.

Another way to solve this is to use the [tool .NETZ](http://madebits.com/netz/help.php#single).

---

If your requirement is to start from a CD you might want to use another technology than .NET since running a .NET application requires the .NET Framework to be present on the client's computer, which might not always be the case.

I would create a native, non-managed application e.g. in Delphi or C++.

Comment: ILMerge doesn't seem to support WPF. Is this the case? Any alternatives?