# Compile project with multiple DLL file to single EXE without Visual Studio IDE

Tags: c#, compilation

When compiling my project, I create a DLL file for each namespace and include them to the EXE I am about to build. My problem is this action creates multiple file, and the output doesn't seem to be portable.

Is it possible (and how) to include all DLL files into a single EXE file?

This is the build script I currently use to build the project:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

if [ -d out ]; then
    rm -rf out/
fi;
mkdir out/

csc /nologo /target:library /out:out/StateMachine.Models.dll \
    StateMachine/Models/*.cs &&

csc /nologo /target:library /out:out/StateMachine.Builders.dll \
    /reference:out/StateMachine.Models.dll \
    StateMachine/Builders/*.cs &&

csc /nologo /target:exe /out:out/state-machine.exe \
    /reference:out/StateMachine.Models.dll \
    /reference:out/StateMachine.Builders.dll \
    StateMachine/Application.cs
```

I am using this script since my machine cannot install/run MSVS IDE.

Comment: Use ILMerge.exe, if all of them are not signed assemblies.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know about ILMerge. Since I cannot use ILMerge, I did a quick googling and found an alternative: [ILRepack](https://github.com/gluck/il-repack)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compile your exe with csc and then [ILMerge](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17630) libraries:

```
ilmerge /target:winexe /out:SelfContainedProgram.exe Program.exe ClassLibrary1.dll classLibrary2.dll
```

There are alternatives for [Mono](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655838/is-there-a-ilmerge-equivalent-tool-for-mono).

Note: libraries should not be signed.